# How to access a public function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not a JavaScript guy, so I'm not sure how to get this working.

I'm using SmartWizard in one of my projects. The original SmartWizard code was extended by someone that is no longer available and is not around to ask.

What I want to do is to leave his code in place as it is and to just access the functions within his class to move the user forward or back in the wizard process.

As far as I can tell, the functions that perform the actions I need are called `goForward` and `goBackward`. How to access them though from outside his class?

Here is the goForward function:

```
SmartWizard.prototype.goForward = function(){
    var nextStepIdx = this.curStepIdx + 1;
    if (this.steps.length <= nextStepIdx){
        if (! this.options.cycleSteps){
            return false;
        }
        nextStepIdx = 0;
    }
    _loadContent(this, nextStepIdx);
};
```

There are also other functions within his code that I would like to access such as 3 callbacks that can be triggered when the user clicks the Next, Prev and Finish buttons. Below are those 3 callbacks that I need to access.

```
  $.fn.smartWizard.defaults = {
    onLeaveStep: null, // triggers when leaving a step
    onShowStep: null,  // triggers when showing a step
    onFinish: null,  // triggers when Finish button is clicked
  };
```

Can someone shed some light on what I need to do here to access them?

Comment: When in doubt look at the source code of demos. This one shows how to do it http://techlaboratory.net/demos/SmartWizard4/examples/index.html#step-1

Comment: @charlietfl, I don't know how you found this, but you are right, this has everything I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#wizard').smartWizard({  
   ...
   ...

    // Events
    onLeaveStep: function () {
        // Do Your stuff on step leave
    }, // triggers when leaving a step
    onShowStep: : function () {
        // Do Your stuff on step show
    },  // triggers when showing a step
    onFinish: : function () {
        // Do Your stuff on finish
    }  // triggers when Finish button is clicked  

});
```

Comment: I thought it was this easy too, but when I try and use this, nothing happens at all. The file where I would have such code is included but appears to be overwritten by the code that this other dev wrote. And because I'm not very JS smart, I don't what to do...

Comment: Actually, I think this is working... I'm very confused though, because the wizard container has a class `basic-wizard` and was what I was using for your code. That didn't work, but when I changed it back to what you have (#wizard), it works. Why?? There is absolutely no id with that name.

Comment: You mean the 500 lines of JavaScript that the dev wrote?

Comment: I found it, Vijay. There IS in fact an id with "wizard", it's the element just below the basic-wizard class. Can you please tell me how to forward the user to the next screen from the `onLeaveStep`? What would I call to do that?

Answer (score 0):

These methods looks like instance methods, not class methods.

For example, `goForward` is referencing instance variables (e.g., `curStepIdx`, `steps`), so you cannot call it as a class method. You'll need to call it on an instantiated object.